# If statement not working after Type Convertion

Tags: c#, reflection, types

I'm working with reflection and I need a business validation, so I created a class declared in the following way:

```
public class NullChecker<T>
```

There I created a method that run that validation:

```
public static T ReturnValue2(T serviceValue, T dbValue, Type propType)    
{
    T result;
    object svcValueConverted = serviceValue;
    object defaultValue = null;
    if (propType.IsPrimitive)
    {
       svcValueConverted = GetConvertedValue(serviceValue);
       defaultValue = GetDefaultValue(propType);
       var x = svcValueConverted.GetType();
       var y = defaultValue.GetType();
    }           
    if (svcValueConverted == defaultValue)
    {
         result = dbValue;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'm getting this issue when a Int.32 object type comes, even that the converted value (0), and the default value (0) are the same, the if statement is not working and jump to the next line (i.e. 0 == 0). I don't really know which is the problem here, if anyone has experimented this, It would be nice to get some ideas.

Thank u in advance, happy code.

Comment: How `GetConvertedValue` and `GetDefaultValue` are implemented? It's two black boxes. And you are asking why two black boxes return different values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because

```
object value = 0;
object value1 = 0;

if (value == value1) // will be always false
{

}
```

When you compare two values of type `object` then equals operator `==` compare their references - does both objects reference same instance.

Instead use static method `object.Equals` which in `int` case will use `value.Equals(value1)`, which in case when instances represents value type will "unbox" them and compare their values `(0 == 0)`.

```
If (Equals(value, value1)) // In your case it will be true
{

}
```

How `Object.Equals(objA, objB)` works from MSDN:

> 1. It determines whether the two objects represent the same object
>      reference. If they do, the method returns true. This test is
>      equivalent to calling the ReferenceEquals method. In addition, if
>      both objA and objBare null, the method returns true.
> 2. It determines whether either objA or objB is null. If so, it returns
>      false.
> 3. If the two objects do not represent the same object reference and
>      neither is null, it calls objA.Equals(objB) and returns the result.
>      This means that if objA overrides the Object.Equals(Object) method,
>      this override is called.

Comment: Thank u so much @Fabio, I get It now